# Set a parameter into view ASP.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a problem with a View. I am using:

```
return RedirectToAction("CreatePerson", new { PersonId = details.ID });
```

And I have a action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreatePerson(Person person, int Personid)
    {
        DBCS dbContext = new DBCS();
        dbContext.Person.Add(new Person
            {
                Name= person.Name,
                LastName= person.LastName,
                Gender= person.Gender,
                Person_Id = Personid
            });
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(person);
    }
```

And I'd like to use that Person_Id into View, I mean that this value should be saved in database. I see that in url address it's a correrct id, but it does not "copy" into a textbox in Form (inside view). When i left this textbox field empty i've got a error.
Does anybody can help me ?

Comment: you are just passing ID, and there are two parameters in CreatePerson. You can't pass model directly to ActionResult

Comment: Do u have any idea how can i solve my problem ?

Comment: You are redirecting to Action, so your Person model will always be blank. What you exactly want to do? do you want to save data on post method?

Comment: Unclear what your question is. `return RedirectToAction("CreatePerson", new { PersonId = details.ID });` redirects to a GET method but your have not shown that. Your refer to a view with a textbox, but you have not shown that either. And in the POST method your referring to a variable `id` which you have not declared (but you have a a parameter for `Personid` which you never use.

Comment: Let me explain what i want to do. I have 2 tables. And the secnd table have a PersonId - which corresspond to id in Person table. When the application starts I have a form to complete data from Person Table. When i pressed save it's redirect to another action with second Form to fill. And i like to "connect" this two table together by using a PersonId column.

Comment: Explain it in your question (not in comments)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can not pass model and Id both in Post method you need to pass ID in your model for that you first need to add ID in your model

```
public Class Person{
public string Name {get;set;}
public string LastName {get;set;}
public string Gender {get;set;}
public int Person_Id {get;set;}
}
```

In your view set value of person_Id to model

```
@Html.Hidderfor(i=>i.Person_Id, new{ @value = 1})
```

I've set 1 as default. You can set according to your need

In your Action Result remove Person_Id

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreatePerson(Person person)
{
    DBCS dbContext = new DBCS();
    dbContext.Person.Add(new Person
        {
            Name= person.Name,
            LastName= person.LastName,
            Gender= person.Gender,
            Person_Id = person.Person_Id
        });
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(person);
}
```

Comment: It's not what i want to get. That PERSON_ID what i need is "coming" from first table. Action CreatePerson saves data into 2nd table. In your example it's the "Person_ID" comes from the 2nd table
All I need to do is make a Form to insert a data into 2 tables. This 2 tables are corresspond with each other by Person_Id column. First table Deteils have (Id, Street, Number, City) columns, the 2nd table have (Id, Name, LastName, Gender, Person_Id) columns. When the application starts the user can fill form to 1st table, then I redirect to 2nd form/action. HI wannt auto fill Person_id =ID from 1st

Comment: you need to pass id from first form to second form that's is

Comment: THIS IS EXACLY WHAT I WANT TO GET, but I have no idea how to do it, could u help me please ?

Comment: Can anybody help me please guys

Comment: I did it ! Thanks a lot for help !